# Is there a way to change the pixel of an 2 image?

Tags: c++, opencv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVKul.jpg)

[image]jpg

I want to check the 2nd image to see if the pixel is white, if it is white i should change it into a black pixel, and also i should be able to change the pixel of the same spot in the 2nd image to the 1st image to black or white..
Example:
img at the cooridnate (100,100) the pixel is white from the 2nd image and i should be able to change it into black. Then the 1st img at the same cooridnate (100,100) the pixel would be black and i should be able to change it into white. to reduce the noise.

Comment: Which is the second image? I only see one.

Comment: the second image is the one with the color

Answer (score 0):

The below code shows you how to find a point in an image, see if it i white, and change it to black if it is.

```
Scalar colourInSecondImage = img2.at<uchar>(y,x);

if(colourInSecondImage .val[0]==255 && colourInSecondImage .val[1]==255 && colourInSecondImage .val[2]==255)
{
    // Then your point is a white point
    img2.at<uchar>(y,x) = Scalar(0,0,0);
}
```

I'm a little confused by your question, it seems to be that you then want to access the same point in another image and set that to black? Or the same colour? either way you would use the same method as in the code above. change change im2 to img1

Comment: for (int y = 0; y < src.size().height; y++)
 {
  for (int x = 0; x < src.size().width; y++)
  {
   Scalar colourInSecondImage = cdst.at<uchar>(y, x);

   if (colourInSecondImage.val[0] == 255 && colourInSecondImage.val[1] == 255 && colourInSecondImage.val[2] == 255)
   {
    // Then your point is a white point
    cdst.at<uchar>(y, x) = Scalar(0, 0, 0);
   }
  }
 }
but there is an error

Comment: i have this code
void dec()
{
 Vec3f red(0, 0, 255);
 Vec3f blue(255, 0, 0);
 Vec3f green(0, 128, 0);
 Vec3f yellow(0, 255, 255);
 Vec3f marron(0, 0,128);
 Vec3f pink(147, 20, 255);
 Vec3f indigo(130, 0, 75);
 Vec3f midblue(112, 25, 25);
 Vec3f magenta(139, 0, 139);
 cdst;
 for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++)
 {
  int x = l[i][0];
  int y = l[i][1];
  cout << x << " " << y<<endl;
  Vec3f px = cdst.at<uchar>(y,x);
 }
}

Comment: so i want to get the values of each channel from the image

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can loop through all your pixel values and manipulate them

```
 for(int r = 0; r < image.rows; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < image.cols; c++) {
           // if pixel is white
           if(image.at<uchar>(r,c) == 255) {
               image.at<uchar>(r,c) = 0;
           }
      }
 }
```

//// split channels

```
split(image,spl);
imshow("spl1",spl[0]);//b
imshow("spl2",spl[1]);//g
imshow("spl3",spl[2]);//r
```

Comment: may i ask, how could i know is a specific pixel has a color or red in 3 channel in BGR.

Comment: example: 
img.at<uchar>(100,100) to see what are the color in the 3 channels

Comment: If you use color images you need to split the channels first and then look at each indivudual:

I added the code to the answer

After splitting just loop through the red channel:

spl(2).rows etc ..

Comment: is there a way without spliting the channel?

Comment: may i ask, is there a way to make a new image with nothing in it?

Comment: Mat NewImg = zeros(origImg.size(), origImg.type());

This creates a new matrix with the same size and same type of origImg

Comment: may i ask for a specific example
is it like 
Mat nimg =?

Comment: This is an specific example -> origImg is the old image which size and type you take and you apply this to a new mat.

Comment: how would i know what is the type of the image from the original?

Comment: may i ask how can i make a new image with the background white and nothing in it?

Comment: is it somehting like Mat NewImage(100,100, Data_type?);??

Comment: The type of the image from the original is the colorSpace. And you are calling a function "type()" to get the type. 
To create an image with a white background you need to set the colors for each pixel. 
I think you should do some tutorials and read the documentation of opencv.

Comment: when i tired making a new image using Mat Newimage(x,y, datatype):
and the x,y is computer by getting the .rows and .cols, but when i printed it to make a new image it was a lot smaller than the normal size that was display, may i ask why is that?

Comment: hmmm.. that is strange... I wouldn't know why